# Error message not showing if the wrong email and password is entered

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

I have a log in system where there are more than one member type. I need this piece of code to show an error message when it doesn't find a email and password that has been entered.

In other words when wrong log in details are entered i need it to show an error message. At the moment the page just refreshes when wrong details have been entered.

```
        $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($user_query); // checking to see if there is infact a user which those credentials in the DB
            if ($check_user==1){

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)){
                    $id = $row['user_id'];
                    $user_type = $row['account'];
                }
                $_SESSION["user_login"] = $login_user;
                // check the user type and redirect according to it
                if($user_type == "Student"){
                 $student_page = "profile_student.php";
                 header( "Location:{$student_page}" );

               } elseif ($user_type == "Landlord"){
                  $landlord_page = "landlord_profile.php";
                  header( "Location:{$landlord_page}" );

               } elseif ($user_type == "Administrator"){
                   $admin_page = "admin_profile.php";
                   header( "Location:{$admin_page}" );

               }else {
                   $refresh_page = "sign_up.php";
               }
                 header( "Location:{$refresh_page}" ); // refresh page
               exit;
            }else {
                echo "<div class='wrong_login'>
                            <p> Email or password is incorrect, please try again. </p>
                    </div>";


            }
    }

        ?>
```

Comment: either add some css for `<div class='wrong_login'>` like `.wrong_login{float:left;color:red;width:100%;height:20px;}` or simply do `echo "Email or password is incorrect, please try again";`

Comment: From where does the last bracket come from? Also check the source code if your output is hidden there. the else statement should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After header, you must use 'exit();' otherwise code execution continues.

Code execution continues to the very last redirect header, and this is what is followed.

Fixed, with easier code to read:

```
           if($user_type == "Student"){
               $refresh_page = "profile_student.php";

           } elseif ($user_type == "Landlord"){
              $refresh_page = "landlord_profile.php";

           } elseif ($user_type == "Administrator"){
               $refresh_page = "admin_profile.php";

           }else {
               $refresh_page = "sign_up.php";
           }
           header( "Location:{$refresh_page}" ); // refresh page
           exit;
```

or do

```
        if($user_type == "Student"){
             $student_page = "profile_student.php";
             header( "Location:{$student_page}" );
             exit();

        } elseif ($user_type == "Landlord"){
              $landlord_page = "landlord_profile.php";
              header( "Location:{$landlord_page}" );
              exit();

        } elseif ($user_type == "Administrator"){
              ...
```